# Externally Tangent Circle

Tags: geometry, circles, plane-geometry

Two cirles, each of radius 3cm **touch** each other along a common tangent. In how many ways can a circle of radius 8cm touch both of the circle externally?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts about this yourself? Have you drawn a diagram?

Comment: voting to close, this is a really low quality question

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Hint:

use the figure and find the two centers $D$ and $H$ using the rectangular triangles $DCB$ and $HCB$.

---

The  two circles of radius $3$ have centers $A=(3,0)$ and $B=(-3,0)$. If a circle is tangent to these two circles and its center is external to the two circles, than this center  have to stay on the axis of $AB$. The figure illustrate this situation for two such circle. The blue, that contains the centers $A$ and $B$ and has center $D=(0,d)$, and the red that does not contains $A$ and $B$ and has center $H=(0,h)$.

From  the figure we can see that:
$$
\overline{HB}^2=\overline{BC}^2+\overline{CH}^2 
$$
and, since $\overline{HB}=\overline{BK}+\overline{KH}=3+8$, we have:

$$
11^2=3^2+h^2
$$

solving or $h$ we have two solutions: one is the point $H$ with $h>0$ and the other is for the symmetric solution with respect to the $x$ axis.

In the same way we can find the point $D$ and its symmetric.

Comment: Well. Obviously the externally tangent is the red circle and there is a symmetric solution with respect to the $x$ axis.  I simply give a hint suggesting  a geometric-analytic approach (perhaps too brief).

Comment: I am a class 9 boy and so am not sure what is meant by those hints

Comment: @SayDude: I've added something to my answer. I hope it's useful.